# MSSQL / MySQL Support for AWS SimpleDB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

AWS SimpleDB appears to be brilliant solution for affordably and scalably hosting non relational data in the cloud.

The problem is, as it's all API based, it's total cost can be very high for smaller engagement due to the higher cost of a developer with the AWS background or API knowledge, compared to one who can hook up a simple MySQL or MSSQL database on a traditional solution stack.

I was wondering if there were any tools/webservices/applications/database scripts out there that would allow you to place a middle application tier between your traditional web app and simple MSSQL/MySQL database, so that data could persist in SimpleDB, without having to rewrite (ideally any) of the application?

If such a service existed, it would eliminate the database hosting requirements for the large amount of simple (e.g. data capture) applications I host, reducing my SQL provisioning and configuration overheads.

Anyone got any pointers? I'm a Devops sysadmin without the desire to rewrite existing custom web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Just use RDS from Amazon (it supports both MySQL and Oracle implementations).

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/